# ASP.Net.Core userManager.CreateAsync

Tags: c#, unit-testing, debugging, asp.net-core

When I debug the test then I see it goes through the await userManager.CreateAsync(user) but then it goes to the catch where it should only go to if it is empty, which it isn't.

This is the controller:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<string>> CreateUser(UserVM userVM)
{
    ApplicationUser user = ModelConverter.ViewModelToModel.GetUser(userVM);

    var x =   await userManager.CreateAsync(user);

    List<ApplicationUser> users = userManager.Users.ToList();
    
    return user.Id;
}
```

This is one of the test I use:

```
 public void Should_AddShiftExchangeToUser()
 {
    MPContext context = CleanContext();
    UsersController usersController = new UsersController();
    try
    {
        var x = usersController.CreateUser(new ViewModels.UserVM()).Result;
        var y = usersController.CreateUser(new ViewModels.UserVM()).Result;
        var result = usersController.AddShiftExchange(new ShiftExchangeVM() { RequesterId = x.Value, ReceiverId = y.Value }, x.Value).Result;
        Assert.NotNull(result.Value);
        ShiftExchange shiftExchange = context.shiftExchanges.FirstOrDefaultAsync(s => s.Id == result.Value).Result;
        Assert.NotNull(shiftExchange);
        Assert.NotNull(shiftExchange.Receiver);
        Assert.NotNull(shiftExchange.Requester);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Assert.Null(ex);
    }
}
```

Then I get this error:

> Message: Assert.Null() Failure Expected: (null) Actual: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Object reference not set to an instance of an object.) --->

the question I have is how do I go through the rest of the test, not that it goes to catch when I make a user?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: You should look at the actual exception that is being thrown to figure out what is going wrong. Also, catching exceptions isn’t really useful in unit tests (you want there to be no unexpected exceptions). Also also, you should verify the return value of `userManager.CreateAsync` before you assume that it was working correctly.

Comment: When it goes in the catch it should be empty. it says: Assert.Null() Failure Expected: (Null)

Comment: @Samantha if it goes in the catch then it mean an exception has been thrown. Therefore `ex` will not be *null* and `Assert.Null(ex)` WILL fail.

Comment: @Samantha This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Share us a demo which could reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your function is attempting to do.  You attempt to get the user, following which you attempt to create the user and then list all users before returning the id for the original get user request.

If the user does not exist initially then

```
ModelConverter.ViewModelToModel.GetUser(userVM)
```

will this return a null object when the user is not found or raise an exception?  If it's the former, then

```
return user.Id;
```

will raise a null exception.

In addition, the create and list users lines do not seem to be relevant to the rest of the function as you do not utilise their responses for anything.  Is this code sample the full copy of the function?